# What causes square faces to glitch all of a sudden

Tags: modeling, vertices

Currently I´m trying to model a simple house floor by floor which was working out pretty good.
Now, all of a sudden, I noticed that my faces glitched out and became all kind of forms instead of squares.

I´m completly new to Blender and have no clue on what to research so excuse this absolute beginner question.

**Behavior:**

- as showed in the screenshot a fair amount of faces became different shapes
- when tried to remove those faces I´ve noticed that there are multiple faces behind each other means I need to delete a huge amount of faces to "break through the wall"
- also showed in second screenshot parts of my wall disappeared

**What I did:**

- all items are basically planes sized to my needs + extruded
- cutted out windows and other elements
- on top face did a subdivide to have a vertex in the middle to exactly place a cylinder for a cut out

I already tried to un-subdivide the top face aswell as did a merge by distance on this wall unfortunately without success.

**My Questions for this are basically:**

- is there an easy way to fix this?
- what causes this issue so I know how to avoid it in the future?

**EDIT**
Blend File attached

[image]

Thanks in advance[image: Glitched out faces]
[image: Wall parts missing]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @JohnEason attached the file, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes. You have lots of duplicate faces. My guess is that in a lot of cases you've pressed the 'E' key more than once before actually moving the face that you're trying to extrude. This wil produce a duplicate face in the same exact place as the original. As far as 'faces becoming different shapes', when you cut a hole in the centre of a face for a window, Blender will automatically create two edges to the nearest existing vertexes as you can't have a hole which isn't connected to other vertices of the mesh in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Most common cause for this is stuff beginners do by accident. The solution is to mind everything you do carefully. Every key you press might be a hotkey for some operation and some changes in geometry might not be visible straight away. It's also possible to enable features (like proportional editing( <kbd>O</kbd> )) or temporary snapping( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  while in transform operation) by accident or enable something and forget about it. Like Auto Merge:

[image]

Those are just few random example, there are hundreds if not thousands of things you may do by accident.

It's also common to perform operations on something selected by accident or not everything what is wanted selected.

If you do anything with any computer input device while you work, you should be aware of what it does exactly. If you do something and are not sure if it performed some action, you can go to Edit -> Undo History, to see if you need to undo something.

Not knowing how some operations function precisely is also something that might lead to issues. You might expect one thing while in reality some operations work in a different way. This, unfortunately is harder to solve than just minding what you do, because you need to be familiar with how every function works. Not sure what would be the best advice here, because obviously learning everything takes loads of time, so maybe just try to limit what you do to only functions you know well when working on something important and stop to inspect things and learn when you start using some functionality you are not yet very familiar with.

The best solution for current issue would probably be to just delete and redo the broken parts from scratch. The forms are not complicated, so it should't take long and it should be faster to remodel this then to fix it. If it does take long, it means you still need to improve your modelling skills for this particular task and the good thing is that in this case the time it takes is not a waste, because you are actually learning and it's simply necessary and unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your wall, you need to fix them all:

Holes that you need to fill

[image]

Overlapping faces:

[image]

Inner faces (plus they are overlapping with other inner faces):

[image]

Vertices that are not part of the adjacent face:

[image]